# Save data into json file in local storage

Tags: javascript, json, html, backbone.js, local-storage

I have HTML5 game develope on Backbone. It's using local storage when you want use edit menu and edit the world. Also you can change your character with this menu. So I want add character select before game start, but I really don't know how to insert it into file.
File looks like this:

```
3:"{"viewportBottom":0,"id":3,"tiles":[],"x":0,"y":0,"tileWidth":32,"tileHeight":32,"width":212,"height":17,"backgroundColor":"rgba(66, 66, 255, 1)","name":"level_1-1","sprites":[
{"name":"ground-ug","state":"idle","sequenceIndex":0,"x":32,"y":512},
{"name":"ground-ug","state":"idle","sequenceIndex":0,"x":0,"y":512},
{"name":"ground-ug","state":"idle","sequenceIndex":0,"x":64,"y":512},
{"name":"ground-ug","state":"idle","sequenceIndex":0,"x":128,"y":512},
{"name":"luigi","state":"idle-right","sequenceIndex":0,"x":192,"y":448,"velocity":0,"acceleration":0,"yVelocity":0,"yAcceleration":0}
],"savedOn":"2015-07-31T14:29:08.725Z","state":"play","viewportTop":0,"viewportRight":0,"viewportLeft":0,"time":748}"
```

For example I want change Luigi to Mario, but I'm really noob with that.

```
        <p id="Character" onclick="choose('mario')">Mario</p>

        <script>

            var character;
function choose(choice){
    character = choice;
}


            var parsed = JSON.parse(myJSONData, function(k, v) {
                    if (v === "mario") 
                        this.value = character;
                    else
                        return v;
                });
    }
        </script>
```

BTW it's not working :D Also I have no idea how to store it in to the local storage. I was looking in to the documentation and I'm not much smarter from that :D
Documentation for this Backbone based game: http://martindrapeau.github.io/backbone-game-engine/

Would somebody help me please? :) Thank you.

Comment: So whats the matter. Parse the object which holds your game stats with json. And save it in local storage, as local storage accepts only key value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

To store something to local storage:

```
localStorage.variableName = 'value';
```

Note that local storage only allows you to work with `strings`, so storing JSON data means performing `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Retrieving from local storage is as easy as:

```
var dataStr = localStorage.variableName;
```

Comment: Well yeah, but it's already stored in the local storage. I need change value from Mario to Luigi.

Comment: Add `console.log(parsed);` below your `JSON.parse` call and post the result here

Comment: Ok, I write it bad. The key is just "3" and value is whole this: (edit) It's too long, but it's what I post in first post. I need change luigi into mario or whatever, but the whole code is value the key is "3".

Comment: The value of '3' is, itself, a JSON string that needs parsing

Comment: Ok, I don't get that. I used another method: In js file I replace mario to luigi and now i need write the code in to the js file
<code>
var world = '{the code in the first post}';
var res = world.replace("mario", "luigi");

window._world = {
  id: 3,
  tiles: [],
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  tileWidth: 32,
  tileHeight: 32,
  width: 212,
  height: 17,
  backgroundColor: "rgba(66, 66, 255, 1)",
  name: "level_1-1",
  sprites: [

** I need the code here**
 ], </code>